# How to connect to a printer WiFi printer that doesn't have internet?

Tags: networking, printing, internet

if the title might be a bit weird to understand I'm gonna explain.

Basically Ubuntu ( Gnome 15.10 ) doesn't want to connect to the printer wifi network because it can't be used like a router ( the printer can't get internet ).

So my guess is, do you have a function to disable this "security" ?

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day !

Comment: I *am* confused!  What model printer are you running, and is there in fact no router on premise that both the printer and the computer can talk to?

Comment: So this is my printer model, hope this help ! http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCX-3405W/XAC

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned "want to connect to the printer wifi network", wireless printers are not meant to initiate any network. Instead, you are supposed to set them up for an existing wirless network (offered by some router) and send jobs to the printer while being connected to the same network.

Comment: So [here's](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCX-3405W/XAC) the model of my printer, and I always did like so, weird stuff, gonna try to configure it once again to see how goes.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind !
I configured badly my printer so each time I had to connect to his wifi network.
I don't have the issue anymore now so we're all good :)